# Filter list: get only unique elements in objects

Tags: c#, lambda, syntax

I apologize in advance if my terminology is off here, I'm still new to asp.net.

I have a model like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of orders, for which I want to create a copy which contains only *one* elment per FoodId. So if I have this:

```
1, 5
2, 3
1, 2
2, 6
3, 1
```

and I want to get a list like this:

```
1, 5
2, 3
3, 1
```

What is inside the amount doesn't matter to me, I just want to see a list of all *unique* FoodIds that exist in the first list. I would prefer to use a lambda function, like this (not real code, obviously):

```
List<Models.Order> FoodList = new List<Models.Order>(
    OrderList.ForEach(o => FoodList.FindAll(if(o.FoodId not in Foodlist) return o))
);
```

Comment: `db.Orders.Select(x => x.FoodId).Distinct();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably should use `GroupBy` method, like this:

```
OrderList.GroupBy(x => x.FoodId).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the unique food ids, you can first select them and use the [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) method afterwards, e.g.:

```
OrderList.Select(x => x.FoodId).Distinct();
```

Comment: While not exactly what I needed for this question (I needed the whole element), this will still come in handy later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use distinct() to solve this

like below

```
yourlist.Select(x => x.FoodId).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom comparer

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<Order>
    {
        public bool Equals(Order x, Order y)
        {
            return x.FoodId == y.FoodId;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Order obj)
        {
            return obj.FoodId.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

and pass it to Distinct() method

```
var newList = FoodList.Distinct(new CustomComparer()).ToList();
```